# How to automatically call a service in symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, service, annotations, symfony4

I have a service in my project

```
services:
exemple.annotation_reader:
    class: App\Annotation\ModelAnnotationReader
    public: true
    arguments: ["@annotations.reader"]
    calls:
        - [getAnnotation]
```

And I want call the methode "getAnnotation" without adding this line in my controller

```
$this->get('exemple.annotation_reader')->getAnnotation();
```

And there is my function getAnnotation

```
public function getAnnotation(){
    $reflClass = new \ReflectionMethod('App\Manager\BigDataTestManager', 'getAllData');
    $classAnnotations = $this->reader->getMethodAnnotations($reflClass);

    foreach ($classAnnotations AS $annot) {
        if ($annot instanceof ModelAnnotation) {
            print_r($annot);
        }
    }
}
```

the goal of my project is to create a custom annotation in symfony 4, I want show the annotation's parameters

```
/**
 * @Model(
 *     namespace="App\Model\Exemple",
 *     version=50,
 *     types={"json","xml"}
 * )
 */
```

so I want create a service who call a function automatically when there is an annotation on a function.

Comment: You can always call the `getAnnotation` in model constructor, but i don't believe its a good idea, you should avoid do anything except property initialization during registering services. Instead try delegate this somewhere else, maybe `decorator` pattern could help?

Comment: Hi Beniamin, thanks for your reply but I haven't found a solution for that. I want to launch an event for example when I put a custom annotation on any function, so is there a solution for that?

Comment: When do you want to call this service? Symfony has certain events you can hook into, e.g. `kernel.request`. Reading the annotation each time can be quite costly though. You should consider using caching. Maybe have a look at Symfony's CacheWarmers which are called on `cache:clear`/`cache:warmup`. Your annotation will not change during runtime, so doing this at least for prod envs is recommended and what Symfony does.

Comment: Hi dbrumann, I want to call the service when there is an annotation on a function.
Is there an event in symfony that works on any function and not on the controllers only? because there is kernel.controller it allows me to do exactly what I want but only on the controllers, that's the problem.